# Laravel 5.6 - Form not re-populating with previous values after validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple form in Laravel 5.6 which I am running validation on, my form looks like this..

```
   @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

<form action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST">
   <input name="title" type="text">#
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my controller like this..

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);

        $post = new Post;
        $title = $request->input('title');
        $post->save();
    }
```

This is working but when the validation fails and the error message is displayed, it does not repopulate the form with the previous values.  Reading the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input it says I shouldn't have to do anything and it will be automatic.

Anyone any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep the previous input, you need to use the [`old` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-old), as seen in the documentation of your link if you scroll down to "Retrieve old input".

You need to change your `input` to the following:

```
<input name="title" type="text" value="{{ old('title') }}">
```

Where `title` matches the value your have in the `name` attribute of your input.

Comment: Thank you, old worked perfect.  Reading up on it now

Answer (score 0):

You're not echoing a value in your view. I am 99% sure that the following checks `isset()`.

```
<input name="title" type="text" value="{{$name}}">#
```

Just make sure that `$request->name` is passed from your controller to your view, although that may just be the "automated" part that you were talking about... I'll have to check the docs.

Comment: once you use the {{$name}}, it will only call the value passed from the model to that variable and not necessarily the old value in that form input. To have the form return the old value use the value="{{ old('title') }}"